# Troubles with setting a cookie with PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I normally don't do it, but I am completely hopeless here.

I am trying to create a simple system to track leads from ads to a landing page. For this I want to save a cookie of the pages the client visited, but for some reason I can't set a cookie, even though the setcookie() function returns true.

I am pretty sure I am setting the cookie before sending any headers, and I also checked the problem on firefox, chrome and explorer and the results are the same.

Thanks in advance for anyone who will try to help.

```
 <?php
//save the received user information to local variables:
$cid = $_GET['campaignId'];
$redirectURL = $_GET['url'];
//save the click in a database:
$servername = *********
$username = ******
$password = ******
$dbname = *******
//check by cookie if its the first visit, if it is set cookie to the current cid (campaign id).
$cookieCounter=0;
$first=true;
if(isset($_cookie['cid']))
{
    foreach($_cookie['cid'] as $cookieCid)
    {
        if($cookieCid == $cid)
        {
            $first=false;//returning visitor
            $cookieCounter++;//used for cookie array reference later on.
            break;
        }
    }
}
   if($first)
    {
      /*if its a first time visit to the current campaign:
create a new cookie log
update DB*/
    //cookie update:
    if(setcookie("cid[$cookieCounter]",$cid,time()+60*60*24*30*2))
  //set expiration date for 2 months
    //database UPDATE
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
    // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//update user visit:

$sql = "UPDATE campaign SET uniqueVisitors = uniqueVisitors + 1 WHERE cid = $cid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result) 
{
echo "<script>window.alert(\"Success! Update Unique Visitors\")</script>";
}
else 
{
    echo "<script>alert(\"Sorry, something went wrong :( could not update unique visitors ".mysqli_connect_error()."end of report\")</script>";
}
$conn->close();
}
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
     // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    //update user visit:
    $sql = "UPDATE campaign SET visitors = visitors + 1 WHERE cid = $cid";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result) 
        {
          //echo "<script>window.alert(\"Success!\")</script>";
        }
        else 
        {
           echo "<script>alert(\"Sorry, something went wrong :( ".mysqli_connect_error()."end of report\")</script>";
        }
       $conn->close();
        echo $cid."   ".$redirectURL;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $_COOKIE['cid'] instead of $_cookie['cid'].

Comment: i changed it, but i still have the problem.

Comment: But may your problem be another one? I try your script and I got the cookie with the change I recommended. But if you mean it didn't save the updated visitor in the DB, there is another problem that does have anything to do with the cookie.

Comment: thank you so much! it did fix it! who knew the problem is so simple! thanks again you saved me from hours of frustration!

Comment: I my advice could help you, you can accept my answer and rated. Thank you.